# Maintaining a responsive WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a couple of days now.

It's a fairly common problem so I'll explain the situation as generically as possible so maybe others can get a bit of use out of it.

I have a list view on my WPF (using MVVM) dialog, it's bound to an observable collection of items with, say, five properties which are displayed in seperate columns.

I call a function which iterates over all the items and changes one of their properties. This function takes a while to get through all the items so I want it to update each item as it goes.

What are the options to do this so the UI remains responsive, and which is the simplest to implement?

Comment: Just don't do this in your UI thread.

Comment: You should do this work on a background thread, having it callback to the primary thread (using the Dispatcher). If the properties of the object in the list view have INotifyPropertyChanged connected to them, they will trigger a refresh of the UI. You'll just need to ensure you do the updating on the primary UI thread.

Comment: What Jon and Tomas say. I'd like to add that it is also important to give the user some sort of feedback like a loading icon on the list. Assuming you are using MVVM, you could set a property in your VM whenever your action starts and stops and bind a busy indicator to that property.

Comment: Seems perhaps my lack of any practical knowledge of threads would be an issue here then!

Any links to good newbie tutorials/examples floating about?

I've tried a few times to get to grips with it and found it somewhat impenetrable - there're so many variations on the theme.

Comment: msdn has some good info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `C# 4.0`, use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
{
    .....
     //CALL YOUR UPDATE METHOD



 })).ContinueWith( { //something to execute after, if need}..)
```

and when set `ModelView` object from other thread, use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    //set ModelView object properties here
}));
```

Comment: Be careful though, if you want to manipulate UI elements in `Task`'s continuation, you have to create said continuation with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` option. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect - succinct and simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an ObservableCollection Extender that allows you to update the collection in another thread. This is what I use in my applications when dealing with collections:

```
public class ObservableCollectionExtender<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Source: New Things I Learned
    /// Title: Have worker thread update ObservableCollection that is bound to a ListCollectionView
    /// http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx
    /// Note: Improved for clarity and the following of proper coding standards.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Use BlockReentrancy
        using (BlockReentrancy())
        {
            var eventHandler = CollectionChanged;

            // Only proceed if handler exists.
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();

                // Walk thru invocation list
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in delegates)
                {
                    var currentDispatcher = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

                    // If the subscriber is a DispatcherObject and different thread
                    if ((currentDispatcher != null) &&
                        (currentDispatcher.CheckAccess() == false))
                    {
                        // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread
                        currentDispatcher.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        handler(this, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overridden NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler event.
    /// </summary>
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - a good alternative. I've gone with Tigran's purely off of the fact he answered first.

Comment: No problem. The only reason I suggested this over his excellent answer is because I do not need to deliberately concern myself with updating the UI. This just requires updates to the collection which are immediately reflected in the UI without an impact on the UI thread. When you go the route of updating your grid aggressively (once a second), you will want to try something like this instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, and also for people who are working on Netframework 3.5, could be work on a background thread and synchronize using the synchronization contest. Try this:

```
        var sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
        w.DoWork+=(_, __)=>
            {                    
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                   //calculate other things
                   sync.Post(p => { ...Actualize UI code... }, null);                  
                }
             }, null);
            };
        w.RunWorkerAsync();
```